# Where's Footnote in Loki?

Tags: release-loki, software-installation

In Freya I used Footnote all the time and I thought it would come installed by default in Loki but instead I can't even figure out how to install it.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there hasn't yet been a stable release of this app. You could [install Footnote from elementary-daily](https://quassy.github.io/elementary-apps/Footnote/). Fair warning, though: adding elementary-daily may cause your OS to be unstable.

As an alternative, you could use Notes or GNotes (both available in AppCenter), or take notes in Scratch.

---

**Edit**: It looks like there isn't a Loki-compatible version of Footnote in elementary-daily. In [this list of apps](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/daily), neither of the Footnote packages ends with `ubuntu16.10.1` or `ubuntu0.4.1`. You may be able to [check out the source code](https://launchpad.net/footnote) and build Footnote from source, but the app may behave unexpectedly on Loki.

The last non-translation update to Footnote was in October 2015, so it probably needs some love in order to work well on Loki. If you're interested, this would be a good opportunity to get involved with elementary! :)

Comment: I was not able to install it from elementary-daily in loki, only in freya.

Comment: Ah, got it. I've updated the answer with more detail.